# What does blank=True mean in the context of *Integer fields at Django?

Tags: django

I know how to use it for CharField.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/models/fields/#blank):

> If a field has `blank=True`, validation on Django’s admin site will allow entry of an empty value.

And from the [`null` documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/models/fields/#null):

> Note that empty string values will always get stored as empty strings, not as `NULL`. Only use `null=True` for non-string fields such as integers, booleans and dates. For **both types of fields**, you will also need to set **`blank=True`** if you wish to **permit empty values in forms**, as the `null` parameter only affects database storage (see blank).

So `blank=True` basically affects only the **forms**. It allows to have empty form fields. But you also have to set `null=True` for **non-** string fields if you really want to allow empty values in the database as "no value" or "empty" means `NULL` in the database for non-string fields (for string fields, an empty value is just the empty string `''` which is different from `NULL`).

Answer (score 0):

It means that you don't have to enter a value for the field in a form. (for example when you are using the django admin interface).

It's different from null because, `blank=True` might mean that when you don't enter a value, the default value (for example 0) is used, but `null=True` indicates that you can also store None in the field.

Look at the documentation:

- http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.null
- http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.blank